# Using Elastic search for different search website

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am new to Elastic search and need help to understand using Elastic Search for different search purpose.

We have different websites which gets data from different services. Currently, we are using ES and Logstash for one of the website search options.
We have requirement to implement advanced search functionality to another website and it gets data from different databases. I understood that we can use Elastic search and logstash as feeder to get data from different DB to ES.

I understood how to implement ES and logstash. However, I would need help in understanding can we use existing ES with different DB data and mappings. If yes, could you please share some information how to achieve this.

other Option would be, Add new ES as new instance  and use this ES to achieve search functionality in new website.

Could you please suggest how to achieve with ES best practices.

Comment: what do you mean by  "add new es instance" ? is it cluster or index?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - If the data has mapping conflicts that you cant handle (same filed name with different value type) you must put it in different indices, otherwise they can be in the same index but not have to.

you will achieve what you ask just by put the new data to the same index.

**longer:**

elastic stores data in [index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index) (like tables in relational DB).

the index schema called mapping. you can add fields to mapping after the index created, but mapping for a specific field cannot be changed once it was set. moreover, you can't have two different value types to the same field in the same mapping, you will get an exception when you try to do that.

my recommendation  -
if you want to query the data from your new site similarly to the data from the old site you can put them in the same index. In that case, I recommend adding a `source` field that indicates where the data came from.

the bottom line is it depends on more things like the latency you need for each site query and the volume and structure of the new data.